# Writing from System.out.println to a file

Tags: java, file, createfile

I've replaced many strings and outputted the result and now am trying to write those lines into a text file. Here's what I did. I created a new file:

```
File newfile = new File("/Users/Bill/Desktop/newfile.txt");
    if (newfile.exists()) {
        System.out.println("File exists");
    } else {
        newfile.createNewFile();
        System.out.println("New file created");

    }
```

And then I tried to write to the created file the result of System.out.println(lines[i]);

```
    try {
    WriteToFile newFile = new WriteToFile(newfile, true);
    newFile.write(lines[i]); 
    // lines[i] is what I used to print out System.out.println(lines[i])  
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error.");
    }
```

I'm not getting what I'm expecting, though. Any suggestions?

***WRITETOFILE:***

```
public class WriteToFile {
private String path;
private boolean append = false;

public WriteToFile(String filename) {
    path=filename;
}

public WriteToFile(String filename, boolean appendfile){
    path=filename;
    append=appendfile;
}

public void write(String text) throws IOException {
    FileWriter filewrite = new FileWriter(path, append);
    PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(filewrite);

    print.printf("%s" + "%n", text);
    print.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Clearly `WriteToFile` doesn't work. Show the source for that class.

Comment: You need to read a good Java book, such as Core Java.

Comment: Provide the stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call `WriteToFile.write`, it reopens the file for writing, truncating the file's original contents. You should open the file once, in the constructor (and store the `PrintWriter` in a field), and add a `close` method that calls `close` for the `PrintWriter`.

On the calling side, do this:

```
WriteToFile writer = new WriteToFile(filename);
try {
    // writer.write(...);
} finally {
    writer.close();
}
```

By having the `close` call in a `finally` block, you ensure the file is closed even if an exception causes the function to quit early.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the 2nd argument of the [`FileWriter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) constructor in your code.

```
FileWriter filewrite = new FileWriter(path, append);
```

See, it says "append". Guess what it does. Read [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) if you're unsure.

Now, look how you initialized `append`.

```
private boolean append = false;
```

This code is fully behaving as expected. It's just a developer's fault. Fix it :)

Comment: No, reopening the file for every write is still a bad idea, even if you open it in append mode. (Also, it's not portable. Windows has no append mode, for example---it's simulated using at-end mode.)

Answer (score 0):

Just set fileName on System using the method 
**System.setOut(fileName);**

Then whenever we want to print using System.out.println() it will directly print to the fileName you mention.

Comment: Just file name will not work.
Please refer this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13358204/2933389