# Print console window to a text file, java

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I wanted to ask if it is possible to print my automated tests' console window to a text file. I'm new to webdriver and java and so far I have got a print out using the code below. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("c:\\selenium_output_.txt");
fw.write("test");
fw.close();
```

Comment: implement logging mechanism using log4j or somthing , here is some blog can give some idea http://selftechy.com/2011/05/23/selenium-logging-with-log4j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your automated tests console writes to `System.out`, you can redirect `System.out` to a file using [`System.setOut`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29). More in [this other answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851234/system-out-to-a-file-in-java). (You can do the same thing with `System.err` if it uses that as well.)