# i was wondering how i would go about writing this to a file

Tags: java, arrays, file

How do i add an array in a file menu, the code below lets me input 10 artists and 10 songs for each artist.

```
import java.io.*;
public class Music {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader stuff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String inData;
        int [] [] MUSIC = new int [2] [10];
        for (int counter = 0; counter <= 1; counter++)
        {
            System.out.print( "Enter Artist: ");
            inData = stuff.readLine();

            for (int index = 0; index<=9 ;index++)
            {
                System.out.print( "Enter Record: ");
                inData = stuff.readLine();

            }
        }
        System.out.println( "Below is a printout");

        for (int counter = 0; counter <= 20; counter++)
        {
            System.out.print("The nos on Row "+ counter + " are ");
            for (int index = 0; index<= 20;index++)
            {

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

I believe that i need to put something like case 1 here and maybe have the code to write the file in a class above the main.

Comment: I believe you mean 2 artists and 10 songs each.

Comment: yeah sorry about that error

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I just want to be able to store the data and write it to a file while using the given array

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to redirect System.out to a file on the command line. Alternatively you could reassign System.out in your code or better still do some file I/O - all of these have been discussed here [System.out to a file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851234/system-out-to-a-file-in-java)

Comment: would this work if i also wanted the program to do other things such as load from the file, list the data in the file find data from the file etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are not really storing the entire artists name in the array. Here is one way you can do this.

1. Create 2 String Arrays. One for the artist name and the second(multi
   dimensional) for the tracks.
2. For each index, store the fetched
       artist name in the 1st array and the track in the second array for
       the same index.
3. Fetch the data from the 2 arrays using the lopp that you have
   written and write it to a file using one of the different approaches
   mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/java-how-to-create-and-write-to-a-file)