# Add empty line in slf4j logs

Tags: java, slf4j

Do any one knows how to add a empty line in **slf4j** logs without its formatting.
To get empty log I have added empty string as log.

```
log.error("");
```

I need to get it with out formatting, Just empty line, Please help.

Comment: this might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391005/how-to-make-logback-log-a-blank-line-without-including-the-pattern-string

Comment: After doing a bit of reading: you can't do this cleanly and you *shouldn't*. Do you have any valid use case?

Comment: Yes for separate error log with empty line for readability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `logback.xml`, declare a "minimal" appender that doesn't embellish the log message with timestamps or log levels or anything like so:

```
<appender name="minimal" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Then declare a logger that uses that appender like so:

```
<logger name="blank.line.logger" level="ALL" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="minimal"/>
</logger>
```

In your Java code where you'd like to produce empty log lines, you'll need a reference to that logger separate from whatever other logger you're using for regular log messages, something like

```
private static final Logger blankLineLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("blank.line.logger");
```

Then you can get your desired blank line in the log output with

```
blankLineLogger.info("");
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answser is a bit tricky, for me I just use a simple `log.error("\n")` , or append a `\n` in the previous log line.