# How do I see the debug information generated by the -Dsun.security.krb5.debug JVM option?

Tags: java, debugging, jvm, kerberos, jvm-arguments

I'm running a JAR with the option `-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true`.

How and where do I see the debug information generated?

Answer (score 0):

This is a parameter for JVM. It usually goes with -Dsun.security.jgss.debug=true

Afterwards, to see debug lines, perform any JGSS/Kerberos operation, for example those described in tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/.

Debug information is written to console. To see it you can either start jar from console java -jar yourapp.jar, or force showing console: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28477682/1206341