# beginner question: could not find or load main class when running jar file

Tags: java

I am trying to create my first jar file using:

```
jar cfvm myjar.jar manifest.txt Main.java
```

then run it using:

```
java -jar myjar.jar
```

which gives me the error msg:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
```

Here are the contents of my manifest and source file

`manifest.txt`:

```
Main-Class: Main
```

`Main.java`:

```
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("hello world");
            System.console().readLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You did not compile your java source file.  Lookup "javac"

Comment: You have to add a manifest that spells out the main class.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258159/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file

Answer (score 3):

```
 jar cfvm myjar.jar manifest.txt Main.java
```

This should be something like

```
 jar cfvm myjar.jar manifest.txt Main.class
```

You can now also write something like

```
 jar cfve myjar.jar Main Main.class
```

(Also the standard name for a manifest file is `manifest.mf` as that is the name of the file in the archive. A little confusing otherwise.)

Comment: Thanks, I can run the program now with java -jar myjar.jar, however doubleclicking on the jar file gets nothing.

Comment: @J.W That'll need setting the file association in whatever operating system you are using.

Comment: What do you mean by file extension? The jar when I tried to run it was already associated with Java platform se binary.

Comment: @J.W Oh I see. It doesn't open a window or anything like that.  It just uses a console that it doesn't have. That'll be why you aren't seeing anything.

Comment: Ah I understand now; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28477529/what-happens-to-system-out-println-in-executable-jar