# How to redirect output of a Java program into another program file in a different location?

Tags: java, copy, output

I am trying to redirect the output produced in a Java program into another  file("output.txt") located in the same location. I found help on it from [here](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-redirect-standard-output-to-a-file.html). But when I try the same method I find that my file "output.txt" remains empty. My code looks like this:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt")));
System.out.println("hello");
```

Could somebody please point out my mistake here.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Could somebody tell me why has it been down voted???

Comment: Where is the reason-option about "demonstrate a minimal understanding"?

Comment: It was downvoted cause you are comparing apples and pears

Comment: @Andremoniy : I am sorry but do you mean that my question makes no sense to you? And I dont understand what you mean by Apples and pears here..

Comment: @Goldengirl can you describe what you are trying to achieve here? do you want to dynamically create a java source code? Or log messages into another file?

Comment: @Brainhash : What I want to do is just print the output(for example "hello" ) into a output.txt file from a Java program. So this code that I have posted above is part of my main Java program.

Comment: Your code works as is for me. I ended up with hello in output.txt.  Maybe you need to reopen file or your looking in the wrong directory.

Comment: @WillShackleford: I dont know what is wrong when I do it? Nothing seems to be happening in the output.txt file..

Comment: It works for me too. Are you checking for file in same location where you are running program?

Answer (score 0):

As it is said in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13358204/3837150) answer, you should try to set autoflushing to true