# How to print the console output in a notepad file?

Tags: java

I want to know how my console output can be save in a notepad file?

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class HLS1 {

    private JFrame frmHttpsLiveStreaming;
    private JTextField textField;
    // file is accessed to the whole class
    private File file;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    HLS1 window = new HLS1();
                    window.frmHttpsLiveStreaming.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public HLS1() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming = new JFrame();
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming.setTitle("HTTPS Live Streaming");
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming.setBounds(100, 100, 494, 112);
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JButton btnBrowse = new JButton("Open File");
        btnBrowse.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                System.out.println("Argument:" + arg0);
                JFileChooser fs = new JFileChooser(new File("c:\\"));
                fs.setDialogTitle("Open a file");
                fs.setFileFilter(new FileTypeFilter(".m3u8", ""));
                fs.setFileFilter(new FileTypeFilter(".m3u", ""));
                fs.showOpenDialog(null);
                file = fs.getSelectedFile();
                textField.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());

            }
        });
        btnBrowse.setBounds(336, 7, 89, 23);
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming.getContentPane().add(btnBrowse);

        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Clear");
        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                textField.setText("");

            }
        });
        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(237, 39, 89, 23);
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1);

        JLabel lblUrl = new JLabel("URL");
        lblUrl.setBounds(83, 11, 24, 14);
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming.getContentPane().add(lblUrl);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(116, 11, 210, 19);
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Check");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                try {
                    List<String> fileArray = new ArrayList<String>();
                    List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();
                    String regex = "^(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]";
                    Scanner s = null;

                    if(textField.getText().matches(regex)){
                        URL url = new URL(textField.getText());
                        s= new Scanner(url.openStream());
                    }else{
                        s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)));
                    }
                    if(s != null){
                        while(s.hasNextLine()){
                            String line = s.nextLine();
                            if(!line.isEmpty()){
                                fileArray.add(line);

                            }
                            System.out.println(line);
                        }
                    }
                    s.close();

                    errors.addAll(validateEXTM3U(fileArray));


                    for (String error : errors) {
                        System.out.println(error);

                    }                       

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(126, 39, 89, 23);
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);




    }

    private List<String> validateEXTM3U(List<String> fileArray){
        List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();
        String tag = fileArray.get(0);
        if(!tag.equals("#EXTM3U")){
            errors.add("First line in the menifest file is not #EXTM3U");
        }

        return errors;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try reading up on Java file streams and I/O operations. Here is a link to get you started: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileOps.html

Comment: Suggest visiting this:
[Duplicate Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851234/system-out-to-a-file-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect all output to file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674327/redirect-all-output-to-file)

Comment: This is a LOT of code for what's ostensibly a very simple question.  Can you narrow it down?  Have you tried searching the internet for a solution?

Comment: i tried searching on internet.I found but i don't know where i have to put that in my code?

Comment: There a few ways to do it, you can use a logger API (like log4j) or you can redirect the out through your own PrintStream, using System.setOut(...)

Answer (score 1):

It could be a hacky solution , but if you are running in windows or linux then you can pipe / redirect it.

```
java HLS1 > notepad.txt
```

if not what you are looking for , then why not using something called log4j ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write your own utility that has an `public static void output(String output)` method. Then instead of using `System.out.println("...")` you call `output("...")` then in your `output(String output)` method you can do anything with the output, like first write to the file, then print to the console.

Hope this helps.