# Java Console Logs not getting written to disk with an Applet

Tags: java, windows, logging

In the *Java Control Panel*, I have enabled *tracing* and *logging*. I am troubleshooting a Java Applet.

The Java logs appear in the *Java Console* but aren't written to disk.

I checked in `%APPDATA%\sun\java\deployment` - but that directory is empty.

As per [Java 8 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/console_trace_log.html), that's where the logs are supposed to get written to.
I am running JRE 8. How can this be fixed?

Comment: what are you using? Log4j?  Post log4j.xml ;)

Comment: An applet typically can't write to disk.  The Java sandboxing prevents it.

Comment: @Bilbo Baggins - I am using System.out.println to console. However, the java docs say that it can be redirected to disk.

Comment: Anything written in applet code would be running at client side and not on server side. Check for the difference of applet and servlet, Applet gets downloaded in the client browser and then executed by browser.

Comment: @BilboBaggins - yeah, I know it will be running on client. I am looking to get it printed to disk on client.

Comment: read this, something similar to what you are looking for. http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=905078

Comment: @BilboBaggins - I am looking to redirect the whole of the console to a disk file. I am not looking to write anything from the applet to disk. A lot of the trace messages are written to the console by the JVM/Browser rather than the applet itself - that's why I want redirected to disk.

Comment: What happens if you enter 'o' on the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility of the tracing log file location is found from jre8 documentation:

> ```
> If the environment variable USER_JPI_PROFILE is set to <user plugin home> 
> then the trace and log files will be written to:
> <user plugin home>\Sun\Java\Deployment\log on Windows
> ```

**Source:**

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/console_trace_log.html

Answer (score 1):

From the [Documentation](http://Java%20Console,%20Tracing,%20and%20Logging), `Java Console, Tracing, and Logging`,

You need to set "Java Run Time Parameters" @**22.2.1 Tracing** as,

```
-Ddeployment.trace=true
-Ddeployment.trace.level=all
```

Also note that, @**22.2.4 File Locations**,

> If the environment variable `USER_JPI_PROFILE` is set to `<user plugin home>` then the trace and log files will be written to:
>
> - `<user plugin home>/.java/deployment/log` on Solaris and Linux
> - `<user plugin home>/Library/Application Support/Oracle/Java/Deployment/log` on OS X
> - `<user plugin home>\Sun\Java\Deployment\log` on Windows

Confirm your `Ddeployment.trace.level` as well as `USER_JPI_PROFILE`

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

> As per java documentation, that's where the logs are supposed to get
>   written to. I am running JRE 8. How can this be fixed?

Have you tried installing the [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) instead? The JRE is targeted at end users while the JDK is targeted at developers and/or sys admins. JDK 8 comes with JRE 8.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is to redirect the standard output to a file. Without that, whatever you run, it always be in the Java Console

I think you can take a look to this post [System.out to a file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851234/system-out-to-a-file-in-java)

You may have to change standard applet security policy to allow your applet to write on the disk

Answer (score 0):

## Try the other "AppData" subfolders

Try these paths:

- `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Sun\Java\Deployment\log`
- `%userprofile%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\log` <= that's where it wound up for me.
- `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Sun\Java\Deployment\log`

#### Further reading

For background info see here:

- SuperUser, 2009-08-11, [*Why are there directories called Local, LocalLow, and Roaming under \Users\?*](https://superuser.com/questions/21458/why-are-there-directories-called-local-locallow-and-roaming-under-users-user)